# Book prizes for winning weekly competition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In the hope of attracting more entries into the competitions, I'd like to express my excitement over receiving three fantastic books for winning one of the weeks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The first one I've started reading and is great so far, the last two are beautifully diagrammed and bound in lovely hard-covers. Thanks Laura and SE.

Maybe others might like to post their choices too?

Comment: And of course, if you'd like to review some of the books you received (or explain how they've improved your cooking, or anything!), we have a blog now. No obligation, of course, we're just looking for content :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have won twice so far, once at the beginning and once after the proper waiting period.

My first prize was The Professional Chef. A great reference work with the proper technique for all important Western recipes. Gorgeous design.

[image: The professional chef]

The second time, I got both Shirley Corriher books. These are the best applied food science books I have seen. Not as all-encompassing as McGee On Food And Cooking, but they cover many common types of dishes, and go into great depth for each one.

[image: Cookwise] [image: bakewise]

Thank you StackExchange and Laura for the nice contest!

Comment: I like Cookwise a lot but my cover is different. I wonder if the new edition is different.

Comment: @Sobachatina no, it is a reprint only - I checked before choosing. It is softcover, so the cover probably got redesigned for the "new" medium.

Answer (score 3):

I got the *Professional Chef*,

*A passion for cheese* on Rumyancheto's recommendation,
[image: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51FP4HJV87L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg]

And a random book on Indian cuisine that I haven't received yet and so can't review:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I picked up [On Food and Cooking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684800012) and [Cookwise](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0688102298).

[image]

[image]

Thank you, Stack Exchange!

Comment: I think anyone interested in food should own both of these books.

Answer (score 3):

I was the first winner, so I got these two cookbooks, both of which I'd checked out from the library and tested first:

[image: Fish Indian Style]

[image: Fitzmorris' New Orleans Food]

I just made a Briyani from Fish Indian Style last night, so both books have been very worthwhile.  Thanks, SE!

[Capsule review of Fitzmorris here.](http://fuzzychef.org/archives/Ten-New-Orleans-Cookbooks-12-2011.html)

Comment: I love getting cookbooks from the library - it saves a ton of disappointment later on down the road.

Answer (score 3):

I got:

[image]

Which has a fantastic carbonara recipe, and a great technique for cooking duck breasts, amongst many other things.

and

[image]

Which has completely changed the way I bake bread.

Cheers, Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 2):

I just won coffee week and am going to get these two books:

The first book for my inner fatty :D

[image]

And the second book to supplement Reinhart's Bread Baker's Apprentice that I already have.

[image]

Thanks Lauren! :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this one... (in Spanish)

[image: Harold McGee]

Nice!

Answer (score 2):

I've got a well-worn copy of Baking Illustrated that I adore, so I went ahead and got [The New Best Recipe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0936184744), since it seems to be the same thing but for general-purpose cooking

Since I live with two guys who like to experiment with seasonings, I also got [The Flavor Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316118400).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Vegan Holiday Kitchen] - [image: Veganomicon] - [image: Vegan Diner]

Vegan Holiday Kitchen really delivered on a few of its dishes and I look forward to just plopping it down once Thanksgiving comes around and going through that section with the family to figure out who's making what.

Veganomicon is a sturdy bible of recipes and information on the topic of Vegan cooking. It is my personal resource for finding the common denominator among any vegan dish. I have turned to it over and over not only for a few that are the baseline, *nailed-it* formulations, as well as the ones that just hammer it home with a perfect rendition. The skillet corn bread is as quick, simple, and elegant as it is nommalicious and flexible.

Vegan Diner is definitely a cookbook geared to the vegans who don't want to give up their favorite dishes. It lets them know how to not do that. Well-done, but the recipes themselves have a certain same-y quality and turn to the same tricks. But what the recipes lack individually in flair, the book itself compensates for with scope; the collection itself is a good resource for browsing and idea forming. The recipes are easy and the writing undaunting.

Answer (score 0):

For "cocktails", I selected the following books:

[The Bartender's Black Book 10th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935879995)

[image: The Bartender's Black Book 10th Edition]

[The Boozy Baker: 75 Recipes for Spirited Sweets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0762438029)

[image: The Boozy Baker: 75 Recipes for Spirited Sweets]

[Baking Illustrated](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0936184752)

[image: Baking Illustrated]

Thank you, Stack Exchange!